# Putting all elements of an array variable onto their own line in a message box

Tags: arrays, vba, msgbox

The code below is a fragment of a macro I'm writing to alert users that they may not have a sufficient number of compatible installation equipment on an order. n shortfalls (i.e., each instance of an equipment item not having compatible installation equipment are saved in the yankees() array in elements 1 to n. What I want to do is prompt users with a message box stating "Please review your order to ensure you have you sufficient compatible installation equipment- we detected the following shortfalls"

and below that

include all each element of  yankees(1 to n) on separate lines in a message box with two options below "This is okay, I'll submit my order now" and "Let me go back,I want to modify my order".

How can I create such a message box?

I have:

```
 MsgBox "Please review your order to ensure you have you sufficient compatible     installation equipment- we detected the following concerns" & yankee(1), vbOKCancel
```

currently but this only includes the first shortfall. How can I include all elements of yankee() and put them on their own line?

This question really boils down to: "How do I put all non-blank elements of an array variable onto their own lines in a message box prompt"?

```
Do
If rip(qbert) < k(qbert) Then
yankee(jets) = "Your order for" & s(qbert) & " contains " & k(qbert) - rip(qbert) & " too     few " & g(qbert)
jets = jets + 1
qbert = qbert + 1
Else
qbert = qbert + 1
End If
Loop Until qbert > echo
```

Comment: btw, yankees() has blank elements, but the first n elements where n is number of shortfalls are populated.

Comment: Wait a second, woulnd't a redim of yankees() to include only the first n elements minimize resource requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Join` function:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim var As Variant

    'Populate a dummy vector array from a comma-separated list:
    var = Split("Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta,Epsilon", ",")

    'Display the contents of the array as delimited list, use the Carriage Return to delimit:
    MsgBox Join(var, vbCR)

End Sub
```

[image]

The above does not ignore blanks.  To ignore blanks, per your specific question, you can iterate over the array and test for blank values.  I would do this in a `Function`:

**How do I put all non-blank elements of an array variable onto their own lines in a message box prompt**

In your sub, just pass `yankees` to this function, like:

```
MsgBox = GetMessageText(yankees)
```

Here is the function:

```
Function GetMessageText(var As Variant) As String
    'Assumes a vector array
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit

    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In var
        If Not v = vbNullString Then
            sMsg = sMsg & v & vbCr
        End If
    Next

EarlyExit:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        GetMessageText = sMsg
    Else:
        GetMessageText = "invalid array"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you this is pretty good, but is there a way where I can be like, lets say yankees has 4 elements then the function is var=split(yankees(1), yankees(2), yankees(3), yankees(4),",") ? 
I was trying to do something with loops but I got stuck since the compiler expects the right syntax to complete an expression.

Comment: You don't need to use the `var = Split(yankees(1),...`etc.  You should be able to just do `Join(yankees, vbCR)`.  If you need more nuance (e.g., ignoring the blank elements) let me know.

Comment: Thanks, also when you say use carriage return what do you mean?

Comment: You asked for each element on a new line, so, instead of delimiting the string with a comma (for example), I delimit it with a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).  If this answer has solved your problem, please do consider marking it as "accepted".

Comment: Chr$(13) is the syntax which forces a carriage return in a string... Your approach certainly works and I learned from it but Tiger's is more concise so I had to award him the point. I will certainly be using split and join in the near future.

Comment: You realize that `Chr(13)` and `vbCR` are equivalent, right?  Otherwise, Tiger's approach is neat. I don't like the double replace, especially but if you're working with very large arrays you'll definitely see a performance gain over a loop method.  Cheers.

Comment: Great point. I cannot verify this assertion given my limited understanding of how the two approaches perform in time given a specific set of resources, but there would seem to be more instances of reading and writing to memory to perform the double replace across the entire array as opposed to your approach which scans the blank array elements for a criteria (vbnullstring). However, since my background is in math I'm prone to favor elegant written solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim yankee(1 To 5) As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    yankee(1) = "Did this"
    yankee(3) = "experiment"
    yankee(5) = "really work?"

    'yankee => ["Did this", , "experiment", , "really work?"] _
     the yankee array has two blanks at positions 2 and 4 _
     and it also has spaces in some of the element strings

    strMsg = Replace(Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(Join(yankee, "|"), " ", "_"), "|", " ")), " ", vbCrLf), "_", " ")

    'strMsg => "Did this _
                experiment _
                really work?"

    'Yes it did, see result
    MsgBox strMsg

End Sub
```

Comment: Literally dropped your 
`strMsg = Replace(Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(Join(yankee, "|"), " ", "_"), "|", " ")), " ", vbCrLf), "_", " ")` and `msgBox strMsg` and it worked exactly as I had hoped.  @Tigeravatar : What is the need for those replace functions? Are array elements separated by | in memory?

Comment: No, the "|" is just a placeholder.  I used the replace functions to preserve existing spaces with _, then replaced the | (which is what I specified in the Join method) with spaces, used the worksheet function trim which removes extra spaces even when they are in the middle of a string.  That ensures that blank elements in the array won't show up as extras without having to use a loop.  Then I turned any remaining spaces (which are now array element separators) into linefeeds and then changed the underscores back into spaces